# Why doesn't doctest work when module name is same as package name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, doctest

All shell commands in this question would be run from the parent directory of `foo` directory.

Here is how my package directory `foo` looks like:

```
$ ls foo
__init__.py     bar.py          foo.py
```

Here is the content of each file:

```
$ cat foo/__init__.py 
"""Pacakge foo."""
```

```
$ cat foo/foo.py
"""Foo module

Example:

>>> from foo import foo
>>> foo.main()
hello, world
"""

def main():
    print('hello, world')
```

```
$ cat foo/bar.py
cat foo/bar.py
"""Foo module

Example:

>>> from foo import bar
>>> bar.main()
hello, world
"""

def main():
    print('hello, world')
```

Here is the issue I am facing:

```
$ python3 -m doctest foo/bar.py
$ python3 -m doctest foo/foo.py
**********************************************************************
File "foo/foo.py", line 5, in foo
Failed example:
    from foo import foo
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest foo[0]>", line 1, in <module>
        from foo import foo
    ImportError: cannot import name 'foo' from 'foo' (foo/foo.py)
**********************************************************************
File "foo/foo.py", line 6, in foo
Failed example:
    foo.main()
Exception raised:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/doctest.py", line 1329, in __run
        compileflags, 1), test.globs)
      File "<doctest foo[1]>", line 1, in <module>
        foo.main()
    NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   2 of   2 in foo
***Test Failed*** 2 failures.
```

Why does the doctest fail for `foo/foo.py`?